# exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pandoc

I'm using WSL with docker (with a complex pandoc configuration with latex, python and pandoc-filters) and trying a long command with `--filter=filters/the_filter.sh` that results in an error:

```sh
Error running filter filters/the_filter.sh: ./filters/the_filter.sh: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

My filter is a `.sh` wrapper, mostly to make sure I'm using Python3 (which may not be needed, but I got the hint from [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1096)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
python3 filters/the_filter.py $@
```

[Googling the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=allintext:%22exec%3A%20does%20not%20exist%20(No%20such%20file%20or%20directory)%22) shows lots of GitHub issues, but no definitive explanation on Stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my `.sh` file had Windows line endings: `\r\n`.
I assume that the system was trying to find `/bin/sh\r` but the error message is not explaining it.

Correcting the line-endings using `dos2unix filters/the_filter.sh`, I was able to get rid of the error.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/896880/148933) are more details of a related problem.

Comment: Hi @Fuhrmanator, did you solve the issue? Not sure, but I think you should accept your own answer.

Comment: @Gabriele one must wait two days before accepting one's own answer.

Comment: I see, I didn't know :)

Comment: When writing a filter with panflute I found that having CRLF line endings in the python filter itself caused this error too.